# can I specify a maven project.artifactId at runtime?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven POM that I'd like to use as a template, producing artifacts with different names depending on what arguments I pass to it.  But I can't figure out how to specify the artifactId at runtime.

If I parameterize the `<artifactId>` element like this:

```
<artifact>foo-${bar}</artifact>
```

maven complains:

[WARNING] 'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant.

If I leave out `<artifactId>` in the POM and try to specify it on the command line with

```
mvn -Dproject.artifactId=foo ...
```

maven complains:

[ERROR] 'artifactId' is missing.

Is there another trick I could use to accomplish this, other than resorting to generating the POM file on-the-fly from a template?  [Hmm, maybe I could do that using maven resource filtering...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get it right you want to reuse a blueprint maven application and be able to change the artifactId.

This use case can be best accomplished with **Maven archetypes**. See [this to get you started](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html). It's fairly straight forward and its worth learning. You have your normal Maven project and you add variables like `${groupId}` in your blueprint pom. They then get replaced by parameters given by you at the archetype generation:

```
mvn archetype:generate                                  \
-DarchetypeGroupId=<archetype-groupId>                \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=<archetype-artifactId>          \
-DarchetypeVersion=<archetype-version>                \
-DgroupId=<my.groupid>                                \
-DartifactId=<my-artifactId>
```

There are also a lot of archetypes created by people on GitHub where you can learn more about structuring and filtering in Maven archetypes [For example](https://github.com/jboss-eap/wfk-archetypes/blob/master/spring-mvc-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml).

Alternatively you can try to set up the Maven filtering without using the archetype system but I have no experience with that. I don't think you can run a project without it having a valid artifactId, some generation must happen before that (like in generating from an archetype) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good fit.  Seems like every maven question has an answer of the form "there's a plugin for that" :-).  I suspect that my idea of using maven filtering would have ended up being kind of a poor man's archetype, so it makes sense to go with something proven instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree that archetypes are the way to go, but it does not really answer the question. Even if it is a totally bad practise, is it possible to set the artifactId at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set the artifactId at runtime (I use the following solution for a monorepository containing multiple applications). Your project pom.xml should include:

```
<project>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId> 
  ...
  <properties>
    <artifactId>defaultArtifactId</artifactId>
  </properties>
  ...
```

To set the artifactId at runtime use the `mvn` command with the `-DartifactId=foo` option.

Example : `mvn verify -DartifactId=foo`

Comment: This approach works, but will generate warnings from Maven: "It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build. For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects."

Comment: Your are right, but if you know what you are doing, this solution causes no problem. I've been using it for a few years in a production environment without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are going against a maven principle which is that a pom supposedly represents a self contained project generating a stable artifact (i.e. avoid parametric builds that cannot be reproduced easily).

If that's really what you want, I would use maven-install-plugin as a lifecycle step (and specifically install-file) and parameterized that rather than try to parameterize the artifactId of the pom itself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  My build is somewhat parameterized already (and maven doesn't seem to discourage this too much, considering its built-in support for getting properties from the command line, environment, etc.).  But I'm admittedly a maven rookie.  What I need to do is take a "factory" project and build many variations of it that differ only slightly, producing different artifacts.  I'll take a look at install-file.