# How to set the Maven artifactId at runtime?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I would like to define the artifactId in a POM at runtime. I am aware from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954890) that this is bad practise and Maven archetypes should be used instead, but I would really like to know if it is possible at all.

Currently I have a POM with an artifactId like this:

```
<artifactId>myproject${var}</artifactId>
```

and I can successfully build the project by setting the variable on the command line:

```
mvn install -Dvar=justatest
```

Now is it possible to change this input variable at runtime? For example convert it to uppercase (e.g. with the gmaven-plugin) or similar?

Comment: What do you mean by runtime? Do you mean during the Maven build?

Comment: Yes, during a 'mvn build'

Comment: What is the use case for that?

Comment: The use case is as simple as described in the question. I have a POM that builds sucessfully and is named after an incoming parameter and I want to change that parameter to upper case.

Comment: I don't see the use case except that you wrote you would like to do so....So in result it does not make sense. This produces non reproducible builds. Changing the artifactId does not make sense. I would assume you will not change the names of your java classes via a property ?

Comment: Yes, I agree my use case does not make sense. I even wrote in the question that I am aware it is bad practice. Still I am curious if it is possible at all or if someone can give me an explanation why it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** change the artifactId at build-time. It is part of the Maven coordinates (groupId:artifactId:version) so it must be fixed.

All other parameters you could change during the build with the `maven-antrun-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>touppercase</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <property name="varUpper" value="${var}"/>
                    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
                        property = project.getProperty("varUpper");
                        project.setProperty("varUpper", property.toUpperCase());
                    ]]> </script>
                </target>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After this execution, Maven will have a new property called `${varUpper}` that is uppercased `${var}`. You need to set the correct phase to the snippet above to match your build process.

Comment: This does not work for changing the project's <artifactId>. There seems to be no early enough phase for applying this script to change the "project.artifactId" property.

Comment: @dokaspar You _cannot_ change the artifactId at build-time. It is part of the Maven coordinates (groupId:artifactId:version) so it **must** be fixed. This solution will work for all the other properties.

Comment: That was the real answer I was looking for :D